# can't use restful service with php

Tags: php, web-services, rest, post, restful-url

I'm using restful service in order to make **get** and **post** requests with php, it's a ready made code [here](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-php.html), it works fine with the *get process* but it does't work when coming to the *post*, i'm only assigning the parameters that it will be passed to the function, for example like that:

```
 $resp = httpRequest("http://wordpress.org/",
        80, "POST", "/support/topic/junk-after-document-element-breaking-feed",
        array("replies" => "3"));
```

Comment: What do you get in `$resp`?

Comment: **404 not found** page

Comment: Why weather.yahooapis.com should answer on POST? http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ RSS Request section talk just about GET.

Comment: So in general you requested an existing URL with a wrong method or you requested an URL that does not exist.

Comment: i had also triad some other addresses like google support

Comment: i wanna you try to get it work to see if there's something wrong with my assignments

Comment: So try it on your own test script and look on $_POST, $_GET, $_SERVER

Comment: @Astery i'm not sure if i getting your point, there is a GET part i already tested and it works so well

Comment: Send an `OPTIONS` request to get all available methods. And 404 is not correct response for invalid method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use post method on url of service if service not provide this.
Even if service answer on GET it not allow us to believe that it answers on POST.

Roughly this is two separated links.

```
GET  /weather - return some content (or 404 if not exist).
POST /weather - return another content (or 404 if not exist).
```

Following to http standards or REST approach is on developers shoulders. If documentation of service not describe requests with POST method, so most probably there no such API(even if you see REST sign market booklets).